# What is the difference between PERMUTATION() and PERMUT()?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

In Google Sheets, there are two functions, `PERMUTATION()` and `PERMUT()`, both of which seem to calculate `nPk` in math.

What's the difference?

As far as I tested, both work the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that `PERMUTATION()` does **not** exist. `PERMUTATIONA()` does exist.

And

> As far as I tested, both work the same.

no.

Though `PERMUT()` and `PERMUTATIONA()` have similar names, they are totally different.

`PERMUT(n, k)` is defined as `nPk` in math whilst `PERMUTATIONA(n, k)` is defined as `n^k` (or `POW(n, k)`).

More strictly, `PERMUTATIONA(n, k)` is subtly difference from `POW(n, k)`. As [the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368324) says,

> Both arguments are truncated to integers.

Compare `POW(3.14, 3) (= 30.959144)` with `PERMUTATIONA(3.14, 3) (= 27)`.